# how to configure my eclipse for firebase content assist in web develpment?

Tags: eclipse, web, firebase, content-assist

I use eclipse IDE for web development. It is a fairly good IDE. However, I don't know how to configure it for content assist (such as auto-complete suggestions) in doing firebase web development.

Anybody has found anything on this? I am also open to use other IDE if it provides significantly better advantages compared to eclipse?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "Firebase content assist". But if you mean the Firebase Assistant plugin for Android Studio, that plugin is only available for Android Studio.

Comment: right now I am only interested for development using firebase web api. By "Content Assist" I mean auto suggestion by the editor as and when we are writing the code so that we don't have to remember all the details of the language and code fast.

Comment: On the sideline I will also be interested to know about your views on the best IDE to code javascript. I am currently using eclipse for it however not completely happy with its delivery.

Comment: Recommending tools is off-topic on Stack Overflow, so I'm going to vote to close your question. But there are so many good options these days. I personally most regularly use Atom and VIM to edit my JavaScript code. Of course IntelliJ and WebStorm are great options too. And I really should check out VSCode too.

Comment: Thanks frank for answering that. And if it is offtopic, I am new and I did not know this. However, I am really interested  to know, how to configure eclipse or any other IDE to get content assist for firebase web development cause I think it should be possible.

Comment: Yup. And that part of your question is not off topic (on topic?). I just don't have an answer there, hence my comments.